# Deserialising json with JSON.NET - Cannot deserialise because the type requires a JSON array c#

Tags: c#, json.net

This is my json

```
{
   "odata.metadata" : "",
   "value" : [
      {
         "ItemCode" : "NUOVO_ELEMENT1406",
         "ItemName" : "Prova3",
         "QuantityOnStock" : 0.0
      },
      {
         "ItemCode" : "NUOVO_ELEMENT14506",
         "ItemName" : "Prova3",
         "QuantityOnStock" : 0.0
      },
      {
         "ItemCode" : "NUOVO_ELEMENT1455106",
         "ItemName" : "Prova3",
         "QuantityOnStock" : 0.0
      },
      {
         "ItemCode" : "NUOVO_ELEMENT1455a106",
         "ItemName" : "Prova3",
         "QuantityOnStock" : 0.0
      },
      {
         "ItemCode" : "NUOVO_ELEMENT145574a106",
         "ItemName" : "Prova3",
         "QuantityOnStock" : 0.0
      },
      {
         "ItemCode" : "NUOVO_ELEMENT16",
         "ItemName" : "Prova3",
         "QuantityOnStock" : 0.0
      },
      {
         "ItemCode" : "NUOVO_ELEMENT1d6",
         "ItemName" : "Prova3",
         "QuantityOnStock" : 0.0
      },
      {
         "ItemCode" : "NUOVO_ELEMENT433",
         "ItemName" : "Prova3",
         "QuantityOnStock" : 0.0
      },
      {
         "ItemCode" : "NUOVO_ELEMENT1d464645454546",
         "ItemName" : "UPDATE",
         "QuantityOnStock" : 0.0
      },
      {
         "ItemCode" : "NUOVO_ELEMENT433787079",
         "ItemName" : "Prova3",
         "QuantityOnStock" : 0.0
      },
      {
         "ItemCode" : "NUOVO_ELEMENT43389898989787079",
         "ItemName" : "Prova3121",
         "QuantityOnStock" : 0.0
      }
   ]
}
```

this is Entity which has the task of mapping the json

```
public class Item
    {
        [JsonProperty(PropertyName ="ItemCode")]
        public string ItemCode { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty(PropertyName ="ItemName")]
        public string ItemName { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty(PropertyName ="QuantityOnStock")]
        public decimal QuantityOnStock { get; set; }
    }
```

With this class, I thought of the json

```
internal class JsonParser
    {

        internal void Deserialize(string v)
        {

            List<Item> it = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Item>>(v);
            foreach (Item item in it)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("{0},{1}", item.ItemName, item.ItemCode);
            }

        }
    }
```

I tried to remove List and use only Item, if my json contains only one element of course no problem, but in cases where I have more
 elements and I try to use the List I receive the error described in the title.

Comment: Could you add your JSON to the question, not everyone will be able to access pastebin. Also pastebin could go away rendering the question incomplete.

Comment: the part which is the array of `Item` objects is within the `value` property in the JSON. So you either need to target that specifically for your deserialisation, or use a wrapper class to represent the object which encloses the array and deserialise to that. e.g. `public class SomeClass { public List<Item> value { get; set; }` etc

Comment: Your are passing Object here instead of JSON array to `Deserialize()` method. It will work fine with this input `[{ItemCode:'ItemCode1',ItemName:'ItemName1',QuantityOnStock:'10.25'},{ItemCode:'ItemCode2',ItemName:'ItemName2',QuantityOnStock:'10.25'}]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because the object you are trying to deserialize is not correct, you should try following class:

```
public class Rootobject
{
    [JsonProperty("odata.metadata")]
    public string odatametadata { get; set; }
    public Value[] value { get; set; }
}

public class Value
{
    public string ItemCode { get; set; }
    public string ItemName { get; set; }
    public float QuantityOnStock { get; set; }
}

var items = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Rootobject>(json);
```

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: that `"odatametadata"` will need a `[JsonProperty("odata.metadata")]` or similar to work, I suspect

Comment: var items = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Rootobject>(json); return NullReferenceException

Comment: @RiccardoPezzolati Did you try classes as I mentioned?

Comment: @RiccardoPezzolati Glad to help you, please mark the answer as correct because it will be helpful for others looking for an accepted answer.

Answer (score 1):

A `List<Item>` would look like:

```
[
  {
     "ItemCode" : "NUOVO_ELEMENT14506",
     "ItemName" : "Prova3",
     "QuantityOnStock" : 0.0
  },
  {
     "ItemCode" : "NUOVO_ELEMENT1455106",
     "ItemName" : "Prova3",
     "QuantityOnStock" : 0.0
  }
]
```

You don't have that - the root object is a `{...}` object, not a `{...}` array, so you will need something like:

```
class SomeWrapper
{
    public List<Item> value { get; set; }
}
```

and use `DeserializeObject<SomeWrapper>`, then access the `.value`.

Comment: ItemWrapper it = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ItemWrapper>(v);
            it.value = new List<Item>();
            foreach (Item item in it.value)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("{0},{1}", item.ItemName, item.ItemCode);
            }

Comment: @RiccardoPezzolati your `it.value = new List<Item>()` has thrown away the data you were interested in... just remove that line

Comment: ItemWrapper it = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ItemWrapper>(v); foreach (Item item in it.value) { Console.WriteLine("{0},{1}", item.ItemName, item.ItemCode); } add me NullReferenceException, what I wrong?

Answer (score 0):

As @Marc-Gravell answered, your `json` is different from the *Item* class.
To parse your `json`, you should create another class that has a **value** property of a `List` of *Item* class type:

```
public class SomeClass
{
     public List<Item> value { get; set; }
}
```

**EDIT:**
And about the "odata.metadata", maybe you can add to "SomeClass" a property like this:

```
[JsonProperty("odata.metadata")]
public string metadata { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to setup a class to map to, you can use `dynamic` objects.

```
dynamic it = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(v);
```

Then, to access a value, use

```
string itemCode1 = it.value[0].ItemCode.Value;
```